# Installing Wine on a Pi 2 running Raspbian

Tags: pi-2

This [site](http://wiki.winehq.org/ARM) says that Wine can now run x86 apps on ARM architecture.
I need to install Teamviewer on a Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian installed to check if it works or not.

The problem is how to install Wine on a Pi 2. I tried to run `sudo apt-get install wine`, but it failed. I think that's because it is x86 based. How do I install wine for ARM?

Comment: Looks like you have to grab the source and compile it yourself on your platform. The link that you provided lists how to do it. Not sure how well it will work but worth a try.

Comment: it would be easier if you run vnc if you just want to access the GUI remotely

Comment: yes you are right, the [wine package](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=wine&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all) will be precompiled for ARM architecture on Debian Stretch (testing) and up...

Comment: Is it possible (easy?) to install/run Stretch on Pi 2B?

Answer (score -2):

**Regarding Wine for ARM.**

In fact they mean wine can run x86 on x86 or arm on arm, but can't x86 on arm.

For running x86 on run you could use ExaGear Desktop or Qemu.

**Regarding running Teamviewer on RPi with ExaGear.**

1. Install ExaGear Desktop (note that ExaGear isn't free and you have to obtain the license)

   ```
   tar -xvzpf exagear-desktop-rpi2.tar.gz
   sudo ./install-exagear.sh
   ```
2. Run ExaGear Desktop

   ```
   exagear
   ```
3. Download TeamViewer

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wget 
   wget http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_i386.deb
   ```
4. Install TeamViewer

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_i386.deb
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```
5. Teamviewer port for Linux is based on Wine. Raspbian use a bit different virtual memory configuration than Wine expects, so you have to patch wine

   ```
   wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/wine1.6-2g-2g/wine1.6-2g-2g.tar.gz
   tar -xzvf wine1.6-2g-2g.tar.gz
   sudo ./teamviewer-fix-2g.sh
   ```
6. Now you can run teamviewer

   ```
   teamviewer
   ```

   [image: Run Teamviewer on Raspberry Pi]

Based on [this post](https://eltechs.com/run-teamviewer-on-raspberry-pi/).